# how to filter inside Included model using Looback REST URL?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to do include with filters based on `REST REQUEST`. Something like :

```
Albums?filter=[include][favorites]&filter[where][favorites.type]=abc
```

I am using `MYSQL` connector.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to filter the model based on included items directly. But you can have a few options here:

1. Set up a remote hook to remove entries that don't match the included items. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+hooks.
2. Create custom method that call Album.find with include and remove entries that don't match the included items. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+methods.

Comment: It will be added in newest version of loopback? because it not make sense to create custom methods because we can't include models.